# Protractor/Angular cannot click clickable icon

Tags: angular, protractor, internet-explorer-11, redirect

I have the following Protractor/Angular script:

```
clickAppMenuIcon() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var menuLayer = element(by.id('cdk-overlay-2'));
    expect(menuLayer.isPresent()).toBe(true)
    .then(function (){
        console.log('menu Layer shows');
        var menuGrid = element(by.css('.menu-grid'));
        expect(menuGrid.isPresent()).toBe(true)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('menu-grid shows');
            browser.executeScript('' +
                'var zIndexElement0 = document.getElementById("app-container");' +
                'zIndexElement0.style.zIndex = "-20";' +
                'var zIndexElement1 = document.getElementById("cdk-overlay-2");' +
                'zIndexElement1.style.zIndex = "20";'

            );
            menuGrid.click();
            var menuIcon = element(by.css('a[title=Configuration]'));
            expect(menuIcon.isPresent()).toBe(true)
            .then(function() {
                console.log("menu Icon is present");
                menuIcon.click();
                var routerLinkIcon = element.all(by.css('.material-icons'));
                expect(routerLinkIcon.isPresent()).toBe(true)
                .then(function (){
                   console.log("it's there");
                   routerLinkIcon.click();
                   // browser.wait(function (){
                       // expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://10.22.1.68:8080/configuration');
                   // },5000);
                   expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://10.22.1.68:8080/configuration');
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

that applies to the Angular HTML:

```
<mat-card _ngcontent-c8="" class="app-menu mat-card ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="menu-grid">
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" title="NPW">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" title="Upload">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">file_upload</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" title="Correlate">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">share</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" routerlink="workspaces" title="Workspace" ng-reflect-query-params="[object Object]" ng-reflect-router-link="workspaces" href="/workspaces">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">content_copy</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" title="Help">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">help</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" title="Send Notification">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">add_alert</i>
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" routerlink="configuration" title="Configuration" ng-reflect-router-link="configuration" href="/configuration">
      <i _ngcontent-c8="" class="material-icons">settings_applications</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

It returns in console that it finds it and that it should then be clickable to redirect the URL to the new one, but it seems to sit there and do nothing, except to return this error:

```
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) ConfigNavCheck should navigate to Configuration page on click
  - Failed: Element not clickable at point (450,676). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]" matRipple="" ng-reflect-centered="true"></div>
  Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
  System info: host: 'A0000872', ip: '10.22.73.23', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 20 secs.
[13:58:50] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[13:58:50] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:58:50] I/launcher - internet explorer #01 failed 1 test(s)
[13:58:50] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[13:58:50] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

What can be done to redirect a page to the clicked link.  We have tried wait and it times out.  We also had a much simpler version that worked fine with Chrome and Firefox, but would not work for IE11.  IE has to be supported, so that is necessary.

Comment: It would be useful if you could point for us the line `450`. In the code I see two clicks: `menuGrid.click();` and `routerLinkIcon.click();`

Comment: @lealceldeiro Sorry missed it when copying over.  Thanks for responding though.  A click for `menuIcon` is in there now.  As well, that's what's so weird, that I've almost identified where to click twice, and tried clicking on the identified locations with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm going to get some bad remarks about doing it this way, but it works, at least, in I.E., Chrome, and Firefox.:

browser.executeScript('document.querySelector(\'[routerlink="configuration"]\').click();');

Now, if you are having trouble clicking an element as something else would be clicked instead, as I have seen in a lot of Protractor login problems, you can use the:

```
changeZindexById(zIndexLayer, level) {
    console.log('zIndex level: ' + level);
    browser.executeScript('' +
        'var zIndexElement = document.getElementByID("' + zIndexLayer + '");' +
        'zIndexElement.style.zIndex = "' + level + '";'
    );
}

changeZindexByClass(zIndexLayer, level) {
    console.log('zIndex level: ' + level);
    browser.executeScript('' +
        'var zIndexElement = document.getElementsByClassName("' + zIndexLayer + '");' +
        'zIndexElement[0].style.zIndex = "' + level + '";'
    );
}
```